# Sort an array by using its first elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Let's say i have a pointer-pointer-char array that looks like this:

```
2-abc 
5.5-aaa 
10-acdc    
3-(the text here doesn't matter)
```

I need to sort the array in ascending order, acording to the number in each string. I know that the number ends with `"-"`. The numbers can also have decimal points and are in the range of `<0;INT_MAX>`. Any ideas?

Comment: look at `qsort` - you can proved your own comparison function that breaks up the string and compares it any way you like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `qsort` with a comparison function that uses `strtod` to convert the initial portion of the string to a `double` value.  Be careful to return an integer `<0`, `==0` or `>0` depending of whether the converted values are `a<b`, `a==b` or `a>b`.

You need to put some work into this assignment, but it should fit in a single page of code.

Assuming the array is an array of pointers to strings, here is a comparison function you can use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int mycmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    double aa = strtod(*(const char **)a, NULL);
    double bb = strtod(*(const char **)b, NULL);
    return (bb < aa) - (aa < bb);
}
```